# C#, Ram usage, and smooth moves

Tags: c#, database, api, ram, flowlayoutpanel

I am working on a small-project similar to popcorn time, but I have faced some issues. 
First of all when I call the function which gets all available movies and adds them to FlowLayoutPanel with its cover photos it uses a huge amount of ram like 3 GB! so is there any way to fix this (this == the below code)? (Note that I have checked the function that gets all movies from database alone and it uses only 43MB.)

```
List<TVShows> T1 = TVShows.GetAll();
TVShowsFlowPanel.Controls.Clear();
for (int i = 0; i < T1.Count; i++)
{
TVShowControl P1 = new TVShowControl(T1[i]);
TVShowsFlowPanel.Controls.Add(P1);
}
```

second, when I type PictureBox1.picture=http://..... to get the cover picture is there a way to ask if that picture was fully downloaded and showed before I move to the next Movie? and why it takes a long time to get the pic even I am using popcorn time same API with the same internet connection 
last, when I add like 80 movies in that flow layout panel, why it's not smooth while scrolling down even the loading process was finished, I mean the pictures show some irritating, random lines until I stay in a specific spot.
Thanks for any help I do really appreciate that!

Comment: @Tewr this is the code you asked for.         public TVShowControl(TVShows TV1)
        {InitializeComponent(); picturebox1.ImageLocation = TV1.tVShow_Banner;
}   //for example the value is http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/lUFK7ElGCk9kVEryDJHICeNdmd1.jpg

Comment: Update your question with more code, don't post code in comments. Add the complete code for pictureBox1.ImageLocation in your question and any other references to pictureBox1. There is either a memory leak somewhere, or you are not virtualizing correctly so all the bitmaps are loaded into memory.

Comment: Also, for anything over 10 images you should download them yourself rather than letting the picturebox do it. There are some static limits in the framework for how many outgoing simultaneous connections to the same domain. For more info on virtualization read [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dancre/2006/02/17/implementing-a-virtualizingpanel-part-4-the-goods/)

Comment: 'I call the function which gets all available movies'
I don't think, that this is a memory efficient approach.Maybe, you try to avoid getting all existing data at once.You,probably, could use some pagination techniques. For example get by N movies for every user request.